# ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'volumes' must be a mapping not an array

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

My docker-compose.yml looks like the below and I am trying to follow the compose file from the docker registry documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/). When i run docker-compose up I get the below error.

> ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'volumes' must be a
> mapping not an array.

```yaml
registry:
  restart: always
  image: sudarshan/registry
  ports:
    - 5000:5000
environment:
  REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: /certs/domain.crt
  REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: /certs/domain.key
  REGISTRY_AUTH: silly
  REGISTRY_AUTH_SILLY_SERVICE: SILLY_SERVICE
  REGISTRY_AUTH_SILLY_REALM: SILLY_REALM
volumes:
  - /usr/certs:/certs
```

My docker version is

> Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638

docker-compose version is

> docker-compose version 1.7.1, build 0a9ab35

Running on Ubuntu 16.04

EDIT:

Also tried

```yaml
registry:
  restart: always
  image: sudarshan/registry
  ports:
    - 5000:5000
environment:
  REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: /certs/domain.crt
  REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: /certs/domain.key
  REGISTRY_AUTH: silly
  REGISTRY_AUTH_SILLY_SERVICE: SILLY_SERVICE
  REGISTRY_AUTH_SILLY_REALM: SILLY_REALM
volumes:
    - /usr/certs:/certs
```

Comment: Add two spaces before "- /usr/certs:/certs"

Comment: Nope - I just tried that.

Comment: Ensure you gave directory names both side of "colon" (and) not a file

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The thing is that you are not indenting the fields properly. Your docker-compose should look like the below:

```yaml
registry:
  restart: always
  image: sudarshan/registry
  ports:
    - 5000:5000
  environment:
    REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: /certs/domain.crt
    REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: /certs/domain.key
    REGISTRY_AUTH: silly
    REGISTRY_AUTH_SILLY_SERVICE: SILLY_SERVICE
    REGISTRY_AUTH_SILLY_REALM: SILLY_REALM
  volumes:
    - /usr/certs:/certs
```

Answer (score 14):

Mind the difference in syntax between the stanzas for
each container,
versus  the listing of volumes and networks at the end:

```
<...snip...>
    volumes:
      - "database-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data"    ## <---- dash !
    networks:
      - foo        ### <---- dash!
      - private    ### <----- dash!
volumes:
  foovol:      # NO dash!
  barvol:     # NO dash!
networks:
  baznetwork:    # NO dash!
  private:    # NO dash!
```

Answer (score 3):

for me as a docker and yaml noob forget to add a tab it was like that :

```
volumes:
bundle_path:
```

it should be

```
volumes:
  bundle_path:
```

PS: it better to add yaml extension in your code editor

Answer (score 2):

I think that you must do lithe that :

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
```

Comment: the most important is : services:
  web:
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true

Answer (score 2):

I was doing:

```
volumes:
   - myVolume: {}
```

But the correct was:

```
volumes:
    myVolume: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with services.db.environments.
The fix was, using '=' instead of colon.

Like this:

```
   environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=someuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=userpassword
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
```